# Android Studio - How to remove a project from a workspace?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle

after many hours spent spinning my wheels on the below, I reach out for assistance.

I added a dependency to a project in order to reference an activity and that worked great.  As part of this, the project that was added as a dependency was brought into my Android Studio workspace.  So far so good.

I decided to no longer reference that activity in the referenced workspace and dropped that project as a dependent.

The issue I am having is that the referenced project (LanguageSelection) is still resident in my workspace and I am not sure how to remove it. The project was removed as a dependent via the 'Edit Libraries and Dependencies' option and the reference was also removed from the build.gradle file.  Plus the referenced project was also removed from the settings.gradle file.  And then a clean of the project was also performed to see it that would clear up any residual 'stuff'.

What else?  When looking at the folder structure in Windows Explorer, the LanguageSelection project is not residing in the folder structure of the host project - I did not expect to find that there.  Also, I do not want to delete the LanguageSelection project, just want to remove it from the workspace of the other project.

---

Needless to say, I am stumped on how to remove the LanguageSelection project  from my workspace.

[image]